# Why would I get a bus error or segmentation fault when calling free() normally?

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers

I have a very simple test program, running on Solaris 5.8:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *paths;
    paths = getenv("PATH");
    printf("Paths: %s\n", paths);

    free(paths); // this causes a bus error
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't call `free()` at the end, it displays the message fine and exits.  If I include the `free()` call, it crashes with a bus error.  I've had other calls to `free()`, in other programs, cause segmentation faults as well.

Even if I allocate the memory for `*paths` myself, `free()` will cause a bus error.  Is there some reason trying to free up the memory is causing a crash?

Comment: You need to post code that illustrates the problem you mention in the last para.

Comment: You can only call free on memory obtained using malloc, calloc, realloc. Some functions return data that should be free'd as well, such as strdup. But getenv does not allocate any data to be freed by caller. http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getenv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not supposed to `free` the value returned from `getenv()` (it's a static variable).

Comment: don't free it unless you know where it came from!

Comment: So even if I allocate the memory ahead of time, some functions just kind of override that and I shouldn't touch it?

Comment: @chuck: Like `char* paths = malloc(123); paths = getenv("PATH");`? The pointer to the malloc-ed memory will be overridden so it'll just be leaked.

Comment: Ah got it - I need to start paying closer attention to the documentation!  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The memory returned by getenv() is not allocated by malloc() and should therefore not be freed by free(). In general, none of the C standard library functions that are not part of the malloc() family should be freed using free(), or in fact freed at all.

Answer (score 1):

> The string pointed by the pointer
>   returned by this function shall not be
>   modified by the program.

It's not your memory to free.